# How to display horizontal scroll bar in ExtJS ComboBox?

Tags: extjs

A combo's drop-down list gets the size of the Combo, and display of items with longer text just gets cropped.

I tried fiddling with Ext's CSS for combos with no luck.

Does anyone know how it can be done ?

Using ExtJS 3.2.0.

EDIT:
Alternative solutions to improve usability will also be appreciated, e.g. getting the list to expand with the content.

Comment: may be this link could help you http://goo.gl/nAMHY

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can add a scroll bar, but I know that you can change the list width with the well-named property :

> **listWidth**  : Number
>
> The width (used as
> a parameter to Ext.Element.setWidth)
> of the dropdown list (defaults to the
> width of the ComboBox field). See also
> minListWidth

For an horizontal scroll, it would need lots of changes, because the list container width is forced, so "overflow" attributes in css are useless.

**Edit : Another method**

You can add this custom css, for me it seems to work well, as wrapping long lines.

```
.x-combo-list-item  {
  white-space:normal;
}
```

Of course, if you add this it will apply to all combos' lists.

You can set `listClass : 'x-combo-list-wrap'` on your Ext.form.ComboBox, and then apply the css only to these items :

```
x-combo-list-wrap .x-combo-list-item  {
  white-space:normal !important;
}
```

*(I'm not sure the !important is useful here, not tested)*

Comment: Thanks. Of course, cropping the data is also poor usability ... getting the list to expand with the data is also a plausible solution - I'll update the question with a request for usability solutions at large

Comment: Thanks again.
This indeed wraps text and does not appear to have any ill effect on the combo's behavior as far as I can see.
Still - long *single word values* do not benefit from this :-(